# How to make a background-color transition that eventually covers div to center?

Tags: css, html, transition

As I am new to CSS transition, I want to know how to make such a background-color transition that eventually covers div to its center. It's like from all directions, or from 2 top corners. I saw once on an iOS app, I don't know if it's possible on CSS.

Comment: No html provided, no css provided and no example what you want to achieve provided. I doubt anyone will answer this.

Comment: I did try my best to describe the problem though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackExchange!

Please, in the future, please provide an **example of your code, the issue, and fully describe your attempts to achieve it. Did it behave unexpectedly? How? Where did it go wrong?**

Yes, it is possible in CSS in many ways. Here's a couple examples showing you 2 different ways to do what is described:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKzWaa

Code for this one:

```
.box{
position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 0 black inset;
  transition: 1s;
}

#clicker:checked ~ .box{
  box-shadow:0 0 1px 50vmin black inset;
  transition:0.5s;
}
```

---

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNVBVY

Code for this one:

```
.box .inner{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  z-index:2;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:0;
  background-color:black;
  transition:0.5s;
}


#clicker:checked ~ .box .inner{
  height:0%;
  width:0%;
  z-index:2;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:0;
  background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: I think your solutions are right. But can you make an adjustment to make it more "rounded"?